# How do I convert timestamp and offset columns to a single timestamptz column?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

Image I have a table containing the following two columns:

- `timestampwithouttimezone` (of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`)
- `utcoffset` (of type `INTEGER`)

I want to convert those two column to a single one of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Can this be achieved using a `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN [column] SET DATE TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` query and the additional USING clause?

Or do I need a separate UPDATE query that takes the offset and sets the timezone of the timestamps? If that's the case, what would that query be? I can't find any examples that show how to update the timezone using an integer.

Comment: Are you aware that `timestamp WITH time zone` does **not** store the original time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that like this, assuming the offset is in hours:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab
   ALTER timestampwithouttimezone
      TYPE timestamp with time zone
      USING CAST (timestampwithouttimezone::text || ' '
                     || to_char(utcoffset, 'S00FM')
                  AS timestamp with time zone),
   DROP utcoffset;
```

Comment: `... using timestampwithouttimezone at time zone utcoffset::text`?